# El botón de "seguir" ("follow") no aparece en las publicaciones del sitio principal

Tags: bug, estado-completado, seguir-publicación

Desde finales de marzo existe una nueva funcionalidad llamada *follow* (*seguir* aquí en SOes) anunciada en [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/209901).

Llevo unos días viéndola también en este sitio, pero hoy me encuentro con que la opción solamente aparece en Meta, pero no en el sitio principal.

Comment: Efectivamente...yo traduje ayer las cadenas relacionadas y ya noté que solo estaba activo en meta. No se la razón

Comment: @Pikoh mientras que en SOja, SOru y SOpt sí funciona ([ejemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37582/28073))

Comment: Acabo de preguntar en TL..a ver que me dicen

Comment: Estan en ello. En cuanto me lo comuniquen pongo una respuesta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como la publicación que enlazas explica, el despliegue a las SOs internacionales estaba esperando a que se tradujeran las cadenas, por eso no se había desplegado en el sitio principal todavía. Sin embargo parece que nos olvidamos de retrasar el despliegue para los sitios Meta, y esa es la razón por la que era visible aquí, incluso aunque las cadenas no estaban todavía traducidas.

---

As the post you link to notes, roll-out to the international SOs was waiting on strings to be translated — that's why it hadn't been rolled out to the main site yet. Looks like we forgot to hold off rollout for Meta sites, though, which is why it was visible here, even while the strings weren't translated yet.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works perfectly. Such a great feature